# What is wrong with this lambda syntax (Java)?

Tags: java, spring-boot, lambda

Just so I don't forget

- Java 8 SE
- Eclipse 2019-12
- Spring Boot 2.2.4.RELEASE

I am trying to learn Spring Boot, and I am struggling to understand why a lambda doesn't compile. Here is the spring boot example (which compiles).

```
jdbcTemplate.query(
    "SELECT id, first_name, last_name FROM customers WHERE first_name = ?", new Object[] { "Josh" },
    (rs, rowNum) -> new Customer(rs.getLong("id"), rs.getString("first_name"), rs.getString("last_name"))
).forEach(customer -> log.info(customer.toString()));
```

And here is my attempt to modify this example to my own needs:

```
@RestController
public class SwitchController {

@Autowired
JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

@GetMapping
public Rows getSwitchRows() {

    Rows switches = new Rows();

    jdbcTemplate.query(
            "SELECT swityp, oldkey, newkey, delete FROM table",
            (rs, rowNum) -> new Switch(rs.getString("swityp"), rs.getString("oldkey"), rs.getString("newKey"), rs.getString("delete"))
        ).forEach(switch -> switches.addRow(switch));
    return switches;
}

}
```

The lambda in the `forEach()` gives an error on `->` which says `Syntax error on token "->", ( expected` and also on `switches.addRow(switch)` which says `Syntax error on token "switch", delete this token`. It is almost as if the `forEach()` doesn't recognize that I typed a lambda. Maybe what I thought was a lambda, isn't. If that is the case, what makes it not a lambda?

Here are my `Switch` and `Rows` classses in case that helps:

Switch.java

```
public class Switch {

private final String switchType;
private final String oldKey;
private final String newKey;
private final String delete;

public Switch(String switchType, String oldKey, String newKey, String delete) {
    this.switchType = switchType;
    this.oldKey = oldKey;
    this.newKey = newKey;
    this.delete = delete;
}

public String getSwitchType() {
    return switchType;
}
public String getOldKey() {
    return oldKey;
}
public String getNewKey() {
    return newKey;
}
public String getDelete() {
    return delete;
}

}
```

Rows.java

```
public class Rows {

private Object[] rows;

public Rows () {
    super();
}

public void addRow (Object row) {
    rows[rows.length] = row;
}

}
```

Comment: `switch` - a keyword!

Comment: Which IDE are you using? Dis you enable Lambda in it?

Comment: `swotch` is the new `clazz`... Or `zwitch`

Comment: Your codes are fine by the way.

Comment: @Iman: As identified above, the lambda _isn't_ fine because `switch` isn't a valid variable name in java (it's a keyword).

Comment: Thank you! I didn't even think about that.

Comment: @user2478398 oh, you’re right! 